# How to read the forwarded mail using javamail in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to read all the contents inside the body of gmail such as message content,attchements and if there any forwarded mail i want to read it also.
How can i do this using java?

Here is my ReadMail.java :-

```
public class ReadMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {

        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties( ));
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, "username", "password");
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder( "INBOX" );
        inbox.open( Folder.READ_WRITE );
        System.out.println("Coming here");
        int count = inbox.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println("Count : "+count);
        Message[] messages = inbox.search(
            new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true));


        for ( Message message : messages ) 
        {
            MimeMessage m = (MimeMessage) inbox.getMessage(count);
            System.out.println("Message Number : "+message.getMessageNumber());
            System.out.println(m.getMessageID());
            Enumeration headers = message.getAllHeaders();
            while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
              Header h = (Header) headers.nextElement();
              System.out.println(h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());
            }

           Address[] recipients = message.getAllRecipients();

           for(int i=0; i<recipients.length; i++)
           {
               System.out.println(recipients[i]);
           }

          System.out.println("sendDate: " + message.getSentDate());          
          System.out.println("from : "+ message.getFrom()[0]);
          System.out.println(" subject:" + message.getSubject()); 
          try {
            System.out.println("Message :"+ message.getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          inbox.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the error, or undesired result/behavior when you execute this?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I want to get the forwarded message details also. How can i do this? @Gus

Answer (score 0):

See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#forward) for more background on the two ways that messages might be forwarded.

If the message is forwarded as an attachment, the contents of the forwarded message can easily be read by getting the content of the attachment and casting it to a Message object.

If the message is forwarded inline, you'll need to parse the message body using some sort of heuristics to determine which part of the message body is the forwarded message.